# It seems that I have deleted my boot sector(Grub Partition)! How to fix it?

Tags: 16.04, grub2, windows, partitioning

Long story short, I messed up. While trying to reinstall **Ubuntu (16.04)**, I deleted my partition on which I guess Grub was installed. So I went was looking at the install options I first looked at the LVM option (I DID NOT proceed after the write to disk window popped up) I decided that wasn't a good option and I would just resize it manually but now I can do any thing with my drive because its a LVM status? (I'm not sure what that is) I can't delete or resize the partition now in **GParted**. My end goal is to install **Ubuntu** next to my **Windows** and storage partition. How do I resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

To restore Grub on your computer you need to install it on the boot partition, to do that, boot from a live disk and go to terminal and enter

> sudo fdisk -l

and this command will show you the partitions you have and select the one that is going to be the Windows boot partition (if you install Windows after Ubuntu you will have to repeat the steps all over again) and mount it with the command

> sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt

where one is the number of the partition you want to use.

then this command:

```
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
```

then this command

```
sudo chroot /mnt
```

then this command

```
grub-install /dev/sda
```

then this command

```
update-grub
```